# Flutter Drawer - Can't edit colors

Tags: flutter, user-interface, colors, opacity, drawer

I'm rather new to Flutter and learning through everyday however I've hit a wall with my drawers. I've worked with drawers before and have reviewed past code and examples online but these drawers incorporate several design factors that I have not used in the past. Having so many "layers" within the drawer code I am not unable to locate the correct place/method to change the colors and opacity.

The drawers work as coded (open/close) and the fonts/icons are correct. It's the background color/opacity of the header and body of the drawer I can't change/edit.

Any assistance or advice would be appreciated. My code may be a mess and full of problems so advice on that would also be of great assistance in my learning curve :)

[image]

[image: EndDrawer]

[main.dart]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:curved_navigation_bar/curved_navigation_bar.dart';
import 'package:welakaone/drawer/drawer.dart';
import 'package:welakaone/drawer/end_drawer.dart';
import 'package:welakaone/screens/screen_1.dart';
import 'package:welakaone/screens/screen_2.dart';
import 'package:welakaone/screens/screen_3.dart';
import 'package:welakaone/screens/screen_4.dart';
import 'package:welakaone/screens/screen_5.dart';
import 'package:welakaone/screens/screen_6.dart';

void main() => runApp(
      MaterialApp(
        // turns off the demo/debug banner on top right of screen
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: BottomNavBar(),
      ),
    );

class BottomNavBar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BottomNavBarState createState() => _BottomNavBarState();
}

class _BottomNavBarState extends State<BottomNavBar> {
  int _pageIndex = 0;
  GlobalKey _bottomNavigationKey = GlobalKey();

  List pages = [
    MyRoute(
      iconData: Icons.home,
      page: Page1(),
    ),
    MyRoute(
      iconData: Icons.calendar_today,
      page: Page2(),
    ),
    MyRoute(
      iconData: Icons.person,
      page: Page3(),
    ),
    MyRoute(
      iconData: Icons.message_rounded,
      page: Page4(),
    ),
    MyRoute(
      iconData: Icons.wash_rounded,
      page: Page5(),
    ),
    MyRoute(
      iconData: Icons.construction,
      page: Page6(),
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Below makes the text above title white (=dark) or black (=light)
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
        title: Text('WelakaOne'),
        // Below makes the AppBar background a desired color
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff4367b1),
        leading: Builder(
          builder: (context) {
            return IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
              onPressed: () {
                Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
              },
            );
          },
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          Builder(
            builder: (context) {
              return IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                onPressed: () {
                  Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer();
                },
              );
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      drawer: new MyDrawer(),
      endDrawer: new MyEndDrawer(),
      bottomNavigationBar: CurvedNavigationBar(
        key: _bottomNavigationKey,
        index: 0,
        height: 60.0,
        items: pages
            .map(
              (p) => Icon(
                p.iconData,
                size: 30,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            )
            .toList(),
        color: Color(0xff4367b1),
        buttonBackgroundColor: Color(0xff4367b1),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        animationCurve: Curves.easeInOut,
        animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
        onTap: (index) {
          setState(
            () {
              _pageIndex = index;
            },
          );
        },
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: pages[_pageIndex].page,
    );
  }
}

class MyRoute {
  final IconData iconData;
  final Widget page;

  MyRoute({this.iconData, this.page});
}
```

[**drawer.dart**]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:ui';

class MyDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 80),
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          bottomRight: Radius.circular(250),
        ),
        child: SizedBox(
          width: 250,
          child: Drawer(
            child: new ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                new UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                  //Color(0xff4367b1)
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                  accountName: new Text(
                    '',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 1,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                      //color: Colors.grey[300],
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                  accountEmail: new Text(
                    'Modify Experiance',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                new ListTile(
                  title: new Text(
                    'News (gen set)',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    // Update the state of the app
                    // ...
                    // Then close the drawer
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                  leading: new Icon(
                    Icons.add_to_home_screen,
                    size: 26.0,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
                new ListTile(
                  title: new Text(
                    'Color & Design',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    // Update the state of the app
                    // ...
                    // Then close the drawer
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                  leading: new Icon(
                    Icons.notifications,
                    size: 26.0,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
                new ListTile(
                  title: new Text(
                    'Social Media',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    // Update the state of the app
                    // ...
                    // Then close the drawer
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                  leading: new Icon(
                    Icons.message,
                    size: 26.0,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
                new ListTile(
                  title: new Text(
                    'Login Options',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    // Update the state of the app
                    // ...
                    // Then close the drawer
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                  leading: new Icon(
                    Icons.touch_app,
                    size: 26.0,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
                new Divider(
                  color: Colors.black38,
                ),
                new ListTile(
                  title: new Text(
                    'Close Menu',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    // Update the state of the app
                    // ...
                    // Then close the drawer
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                  leading: new Icon(
                    Icons.close,
                    size: 26.0,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[**end_drawer.dart**]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyEndDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 80),
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(250),
        ),
        child: SizedBox(
          width: 250,
          child: Drawer(
            child: new ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                new UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                  accountName: new Text(
                    '',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 1,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                  accountEmail: new Text(
                    'Account Settings',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                new ListTile(
                  title: new Text(
                    'Profile & Security',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    // Update the state of the app
                    // ...
                    // Then close the drawer
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                  leading: new Icon(
                    Icons.person,
                    size: 26.0,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
                new ListTile(
                  title: new Text(
                    'Notifications',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    // Update the state of the app
                    // ...
                    // Then close the drawer
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                  leading: new Icon(
                    Icons.notifications,
                    size: 26.0,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
                new ListTile(
                  title: new Text(
                    'Favorites',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    // Update the state of the app
                    // ...
                    // Then close the drawer
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                  leading: new Icon(
                    Icons.favorite,
                    size: 26.0,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
                new Divider(
                  color: Colors.black38,
                ),
                new ListTile(
                  title: new Text(
                    'About WelakaOne',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    //Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, Routes.about);
                    //Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, Routes.app1);
                  },
                  leading: new Icon(
                    Icons.info_outline,
                    size: 26.0,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
                new Divider(
                  color: Colors.black38,
                ),
                new ListTile(
                  title: new Text(
                    'Close Menu',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    // Update the state of the app
                    // ...
                    // Then close the drawer
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                  leading: new Icon(
                    Icons.close,
                    size: 26.0,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
                new ListTile(
                  title: new Text(
                    'Log Out & Exit',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                  leading: new Icon(
                    Icons.exit_to_app,
                    size: 26.0,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try wrapping your Drawer inside a Container and give the Container a background color? Like this `Container(child: Drawer(), color: Colors.red);`

Comment: I tried that however unable to set a color for the container with this method. Not sure why perhaps nested a lil to much at this point? Again really not certain why it's not working. I did use another suggestion on main.dart which did work correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the background color of the drawer by changing the canvasColor in your ThemeData in main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: YourHomeWidget(),
    theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
      canvasColor: Colors.grey,
    ),
  ));
}
```