# changing color of drawer doesnt show color onhover

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation-drawer

I'm making a drawer, and I want to change the background color, but when I select the color on the container, the color change onhover is not shown, if the color is as deffault works as usual

drawer

```
return new Drawer(
    child: Container(
      height: _containerHeight,
      color: const Color(0xff68778d),
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        itemExtent: _containerHeight < 900 ? _containerHeight/_numberOfListTiles: null,
        children: [
              listTile("assets/image1", "profile", ""), 
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )
  );
```

List tile

```
 Widget listTile(asset, text, action) {
      return new ListTile(
        hoverColor: const Color(0xff545e8b),
        leading: Image.asset(
          asset,
          fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
        ),
        title: Text(
            text,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: 16,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
        onTap: (){
          action;
        }
      );
    }
```

is there any way to change the background color and seeing the hover animation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change canvasColor in your ThemeData in main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: YourHomeWidget(),
    theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
      canvasColor: Colors.grey,
    ),
  ));
}
```

I have answered your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67335217/flutter-drawer-cant-edit-colors/67339111#67339111).